# Script to Auto-resume a Paused Hyper-V VM

Tags: hyper-v

Is it possible to auto-resume a paused VM (due to event id 16060) using PowerShell or VBscript? I wish to run the script by attaching a task to the mentioned event.

Thanks for your input!!

Comment: http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/microsoft-hyper-v-articles/management/managing-hyper-v-from-command-line-part1.html see article

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Resume-VM cmdlet resumes a paused (suspended) or saved (hibernated) virtual machine (VM).

Here is a list of all Hyper-V cmdlets:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848559.aspx